# How to handle promises when using (call, bind, apply) with JavaScript functions?

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have a function like so:

```
let maybeRun = function (cb: Function, allow: boolean, ctx: object = window) {
    return function () {
        if (!allow) return;

        cb.call(ctx, ...arguments);
        // cb.apply(ctx, arguments);
    };
};
```

In case `cb` is synchronous there is no problem, but how should I handle the case of `cb` returns a promise (asynchronous)?

```
let cb = async ()=> {...};

let foo = maybeRun(cb, true);

await foo()
```

I want the returned function `foo` to have same behaviour of `cb` (sync or async).

Comment: Await doesn't  do anything to non-thenables, so you could just use `await cb(...)`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't have to do anything special at all; an `async` function just returns a promise like any other return value.

But note that you're missing a `return` in your wrapper function. Your function was throwing away any return value it got (including a promise).

```
let maybeRun = function (cb: Function, allow: boolean, ctx: object = window) {
    return function () {
        if (!allow) return; // *** See note below

        return cb.call(ctx, ...arguments);
// −−−−−^^^^^^
    };
};
```

One wrinkle is that your wrapper now *sometimes* returns a promise and other times doesn't. There's nothing (standard) you can do to look at `cb` (without calling it) to see whether it returns a promise, so that may just be a limitation you have to deal with. (You *can* sniff out whether it's an `async` function, but you can't know if it's a non-`async` function that returns a promise.)

---

In a comment, you've said:

> i didn't write a return because the wrapped functions i need this function for have no returns

That changes things for your specific use case: You'd just use `await` when calling the function:

```
let maybeRun = function (cb: Function, allow: boolean, ctx: object = window) {
    return async function () {
// −−−−−−−−^^^^^
        if (!allow) return;

        await cb.call(ctx, ...arguments);
// −−−−−^^^^^
    };
};
```

Now your function (being `async`) always returns a promise, and in the cases where `cb` returns a promise (either explicitly or because it's an `async` function), your function will wait for that promise to settle before returning, but won't return the fulfillment value.

Note that even with that change, `cb` is called *synchronously* when you call the wrapper function you got from `maybeRun`. An `async` function runs synchronously until the first time it has to wait for something. If `cb` is synchronous, it'll be run during that initial synchronous execution of the wrapper.

Comment: thank you so much), i didn't write a return because the wrapped functions i need this function for have no returns, thanks again (:

Comment: @modex98 - Ah, that changes things. I'll update.

Comment: I'm sure you can write overloads to differentiate between sync/async callbacks anyways, too.

Comment: Oh I thought we were talking about types heheh 

Comment: @catgirlkelly - OMG. I completely read past the types **and** the [typescript] tag. Now I have to revise the answer again. ;-D Oh, wait, no, I don't, because even though we could write overloads, we'd still have to base the implementation on the runtime value of what it received, and we can't detect a function that explicitly returns a promise (including a transpiled `async` function). Still, though, wow on my reading right past the types. o_O

Comment: Isn't there an internal hidden AsyncFunction object similar to Function? I remember encountering it in node.js. Same with AsyncGeneratorFunction and GeneratorFunction. Pretty wacky cursed stuff.

Comment: @catgirlkelly - There's `GeneratorFunction` and `AsyncGeneratorFunction` but that's about having more generic type parameters because there's more to them than basic functions. But regardless, that's type information the implementation function wouldn't have at runtime, which it would need if we were going to base a decision on whether to return a promise on it.